# Netezza/PureData - Bad distribution key chosen in HASH JOIN

Tags: performance, distribution, netezza, sql-execution-plan

I am using Netezza/Pure Data for a query. I have a INNER JOIN (which became a HASH JOIN) on two columns A and B. A is a column that has good distribution and B is a column that has bad distribution. For some reason, my query plan always uses B instead A as the distribution key for that JOIN, which causes immense performance issue.

GENERATE STATISTICS does help alleviate this issue, but due to performance constraints, it is not feasiable to GENERATE STATISTICS before every query. I do it before a batch run but not in between each query within a batch.

In a nutshell, the source tables have good distributions but when I join them, they choose a bad distribution key (which is actually never used as a distribution column at all in the sources).

So my question is, what are some good ways to influence the choice of distribution key in a JOIN without doing GENERATE STATISTICS. I've tried changing around the distribution columns of the source tables but that didn't do much even if I make sure all the skew's are less than 0.5.

Comment: The intermediary distributions used in a query plan are typically determined entirely by the join columns selected.  Can you tell us the distribution columns for the two tables in question, and then tell us the columns that they are joined on in the query?

Comment: Also, tell us the intermediary distribution (good and bad) shown in the plans.

Comment: The JOIN columns are columns A and B mentioned above. A is used as a distribution key for one of the sources of the JOIN. B is never used as a distributoin key anywhere. Distribution is good on column A and bad on column B. Problem is that column B is chosen in the query plan

Comment: Sorry to nickel and dime you with questions here, but is it true that table_A is distributed on *only* columnA? What column, if any, is table_B distributed on?

Comment: Yes, all tables are distributed on only one column. One of the tables in the join is distributed on only column A. The other table is distributed on a different column (not column B).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround is to force exhaustive planner to be used.

set num_star_planner_rels = X; -- Set X to very high.

According to IBM Netezza team, queries with more than 7 entities (# of tables) will use a greedy query planner called "Snowflake". At 7 or less entities, it will use the brute force approach to find the best plan.

The trade off is that exhaustive search is very expensive for large number of entities.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temp table and force the distribution so that they both align, this should expedite the join